# Regex Pattern match and get two strings

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pattern match this string

> ***** XXXXXXX  04/28/2017  14:48:40 *****

I want to get `XXXXXXX` and `04/28/2017  14:48:40`.

So for I tried the regex

```
@"\*{5}(.*?)\*{5}"
```

which matches pattern but how to get the other two values.

Comment: would there ever be a space in the XXXXXXX?

Comment: Maybe i'm not reading this correctly, but couldn't you just match for spaces and parse it from there, assuming that you can break off a piece of this by searching for something like a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will pull out each section as its own Group. A group is specified using the brackets around the regex group. You then can index each group as a dictionary with the position of the group in the string. 0 references the whole string that has matched with 1 being the first (*****) section and so on.

```
var str = "***** XXXXXXX 04/28/2017 14:48:40 *****";
var reg = new Regex(@"(\*{5})\s(.*?)\s([0-9/]*?)\s([0-9:]*?)\s(\*{5})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var groups = reg.Match(str).Groups;
```

The use of the Lazy Quantifiers mean that each group will only match the minimum number of characters for the Regex to match. The \s will match any whitespace character for the string encoding.

The code above leaves us with the following matches in the groups variable:

```
0 > "***** XXXXXXX 04/28/2017 14:48:40 *****"
1 > "*****"
2 > "XXXXXXX"
3 > "04/28/2017"
4 > "14:48:40"
5 > "*****"
```

Comment: It is close but not separating XXXXXXX 04/28/2017

Comment: Can you send me a string that it doesn't match correctly? I am working on the assumption that each group does not have a space in it and that XXXXXXX is just alphabet characters.

Comment: ***** XXXXXXX 04/28/2017 14:48:40 ***** sample string. Each group has a space between them.

Comment: (.*?) Matches the XXXXXXX and is stored in groups[2]

Comment: For me groups[2] is coming as XXXXXXX 04/28/2017

Comment: Hmm copying the code from my browser into LinqPad gives me the groups that I've just edited into my answer. Are you testing the Regex in C# or in a Regex tool? It's the sort of thing that may be affected by a tool although I can't imagine that it would match at all if the second group was matching incorrectly.

Comment: I am using c# and trying in visual studio.

Comment: Ok I've just created a new .Net 4.5.2 Console App in Visual Studio and got the same results as in LinqPad. It may be worth swapping out the spaces in the Regex for a \s (whitespace) as it is possible that you are experiencing a text encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex since the stars and date are always going to be the same length it'll be very easy to extract the content, and in this case it wouldn't matter if the content has spaces or not

```
var a = "***** ABCDEFGEF 04/28/2017 14:48:40 *****";
var content = a.Substring(6, a.Length-32);
var datestring = a.Substring(a.Length-25).Replace("*","");


Console.WriteLine(content);
Console.WriteLine(datestring);
```

Output:

`ABCDEFGEF`

`04/28/2017 14:48:40`

In the content line of code you start at the last star and space then you go until the length of the string minus the date/time and stars (beginning and ending stars).

For the datestring you just start at the length of the date/time and stars.

Comment: Agreed but need only in regex.

Answer (score 1):

**This expression will match**

`(X{7})|([042817/:])` = XXXXXXX 04/28/2017 14:48:40

**This expression will match**

`(X{7})` = XXXXXXX

`([042817/:])` = 04/28/2017 14:48:40

Answer (score 0):

You can access the middle part from the Groups property on the Regex Match object. Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info about the Groups property